# Match county names to predefined list

Tags: levenshtein-distance

I read large lists of county names that people wrote down manually and now need to be matched to a predefined list of counties.

I understand that those matches cannot be perfect, but the operator should be shown a list of "wrong" county names together with their best matches, and ideally needs just to click "ok" to proceed and use them.

Until now, I just use levenshtein distance, which is great for catching typos, but not great for abbreviations. Real world examples that would be obvious to a human, but which levenshtein does not match correctly:

- Input: Siegen
- Should be: Siegen-Wittgenstein
- Levenshtein: Hagen

or

- Input: Rhein.-Berg. Kreis
- Should be: Rheinisch-Bergischer Kreis
- Levenshtein: Rhein-Sieg-Kreis

How can I catch those abbreviations as well?

I use PHP, but this more a question about the right algorithm than about PHP.

Comment: What about adding the abbreviations as possible target names as well and map them back later to the original name?

Comment: Maybe something clever with around a trie, and break input into sections for better accuracy?

Comment: @Progman Generally a good idea, but actually before encountering these examples in real life, it did know e.g. that Rhein.-Berg.-Kreis is a usual abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

As you're dealing with geographic data, perhaps a geocoding approach could work? An example API would be [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/), but there are many other (paid) options.

If I use your two examples in [the debugging interface of Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html) I get the following:

Example 1:

- Input: Siegen
- Expected output: Siegen-Wittgenstein
- Nominatim outputs ([link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q=Siegen)):

  - Siegen, **Kreis Siegen-Wittgenstein**, North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany
  - Siegen, Haguenau-Wissembourg, Bas-Rhin, Grand Est, Metropolitan France, 67160, France
  - Siegen, **Kreis Siegen-Wittgenstein**, North Rhine-Westphalia, 57072, Germany

Example 2:

- Input: Rhein.-Berg. Kreis
- Expected output: Rheinisch-Bergischer Kreis
- Nominatim outputs ([link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q=Rhein.-Berg.+Kreis)):

  - Geschäftsstelle DRK Kreisverband Rhein.-Berg. Kreis, 261, Hauptstraße, Heidkamp, Bergisch Gladbach, **Rheinisch-Bergischer Kreis**, North Rhine-Westphalia, 51465, Germany
  - Auf dem Kreis, Bad Berleburg, Kreis Siegen-Wittgenstein, North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany
  - Region Rhein-Neckar (HE), Kreis Bergstraße, Hesse, Germany

The quality is mixed, it definitely requires additional filtering. Without any additional filtering you get various resulttypes (administrative regions, a mountain peak, a charity) and also various countries (Germany and France).

However, you can apply filters on the [detailed output](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Details/#json) to return only county names in a specific country to get the output you want.

Comment: It did not know Nominatim, it is definitely interesting. The quality of your examples is not really good, though.

Comment: Qualitywise it's impossible for a geocoder to know which country you're interested in, or that you're looking for a county as a result. The country of interest can be set in the request, and the output can be parsed to only retrieve the county name. In any case, it has some promise in contrast to the Levenstein distance approach.